# Automatic assign operator construction

Tags: c++

Could somebody guide me through what gets called in this scenario?

```
template<class T>
class mat4 {
public :

T matrix[4][4];

    mat4();
    mat4(vec4<T> i, vec4<T> j, vec4<T> k, vec4<T> t);
    mat4(const T input_matrix[4][4]);

    //~mat4();

    mat4<T> Transposed() const;
    void Transpose();

    mat4<T> Inversed() const;
    void Inverse();

};
```

With the above code if i call

```
mat4<float> matrix;
float mf[4][4];

//fill the float matrix here

matrix = mf;
```

Then i know that the 3rd constructor gets called (it's not explicit), but what is called beside that? A copy constructor for matrix that takes the temporary object created from the assignment operation? I'm debating whether or not i should create a custom assign operator for it or just let it handle itself. The custom operator would only copy the matrix into the mat4 and return a reference to the mat4, but if there's no overhead in the automaticly created assignment operator then i'd rather stick to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) should reduce this to just a call to the third constructor. As long as you're compiling with optimization, there's no need to reduce readability to reduce overhead in this case.

Also, I don't see how a custom copy constructor and/or assignment operator will have less overhead than the compiler-generated ones; they may even complicate the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If this matrix held a `std::vector<T>(16);`, modern implicitly-generated assignment operator would "steal" the contents of the temporary created from `mf` and would avoid the second copy. For an older compiler, you could write such an assignment operator yourself (see [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)).

However, this matrix holds an array as a data member: implicitly-generated assignment operator, just like any assignment operator you could write, will have to actually copy (or move, if T is movable) each of the 16 T values individually (or with a single memcpy if T is trivially-copyable). Compilers may in fact optimize out the temporary and copy all 16 Ts directly out of `mf` into `matrix.matrix`, but it's a rather more complex optimization than a simple RVO. GCC seems to be doing it, in my test.